# A frappe de / d'un / du martelet

Tags: articles

Bonjour,

> A. frappe **de** martelet au gong pour réclamer le silence.
>
> A. frappe **d'un** martelet au gong pour réclamer le silence.
>
> A. frappe **du** martelet au gong pour réclamer le silence.

[A. = une personne]

J'hésite quant au choix de l'article. D'après [lalanguefrancaise](https://www.lalanguefrancaise.com/dictionnaire/definition/frapper), si le nom est abstrait, on n'emploie pas d'article devant celui-ci.

> Or, la loi frappe **de** nullité tout jugement rendu par un tribunal
> composé d'autres magistrats que ceux ayant siégé à la première
> audience. *Courteline, Client sér.,1897, 3, p. 38.*

Mais dans mon exemple, il s'agit d'un marteau. Donc, la troisième phrase devrait être correcte, n'est-ce pas ?

Comment: Que signifie le A au début de chaque phrase ?

Comment: @XouDo Le nom de la personne. Par exemple, _**André** frappe le gong d'un coup de maillet._

Comment: Pourquoi pas: A. frappe le gong au martelet? [A. frappe de martelet au gong me semble assez bizarre.]

Comment: @ Lambie Je ne savais pas que "au" était aussi possible, je pensais que seuls "de" et "avec" l'étaient.

Answer (score 2):

Le bon usage dépend du contexte, et de si cette phrase est la première mention de l'objet.

"*A frappe **d'un** martelet*" est correct et suppose que le martelet n'a pas été introduit précédemment.

"*A frappe **du** martelet*" est correct aussi, et suppose qu'on a introduit le martelet. On peut par exemple dire "*frapper du poing*", ou "*de la raquette*" dans le contexte d'un match de tennis, car il est acquis que tout le monde a un poing et que tout tennisman a une raquette.

On a aussi "*A frappe de son martelet*" qui peut fonctionner dans les deux cas. On note que A possède un martelet, qu'il ait été introduit avant ou non.

---

*A frappe **de** martelet* n'est pas correcte. Ici le nom n'est pas abstrait, car il désigne le martelet de A. On pourrait utiliser *de* dans une phrase construite différemment : "*A fait sonner le gong d'une frappe **de** martelet*".

---

Aussi, je trouve le choix de mot "***au** gong*" étrange. On ne frappe pas "au gong", on frappe *le* gong, on frappe *sur* le gong ou éventuellement *contre* le gong ou autre, mais je n'aurais pas utilisé *au* ici.

Comment: Merci ! Je voulais dire ce que LPH a expliqué : _dans la phrase « 2 » il s'agit d'un martelet quelconque (un) alors que dans la phrase « 3 » on fait référence à un martelet connu, le martelet qui est utilisé habituellement dans ce genre de procédure (de le)._ Je n'étais pas sûre... "au gong" Vous avez raison. J'ai trouvé une explication : [usito](https://usito.usherbrooke.ca/d%C3%A9finitions/frapper) **frapper à la porte**. Cogner à une porte pour se faire ouvrir. **frapper contre, dans, sur**, etc. Donner un ou plusieurs coups sur (une surface).

Answer (score 1):

La première phrase n'est pas correcte ; « **frapper de qqc** » s'utilise au passif dans deux cas de sens importants : premièrement, le sens « être l'objet d'(une décision administrative, juridique, autoritaire » ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/frapper)) et deuxièmement, le sens « constater avec étonnement » ; ces deux sens sont figurés. Avec en plus un complément d'objet, elle s'utilise aussi à la voix active : « **Frapper qqn ou qqc de qqc.** » (TLFi) ; elle a alors  le sens « provoquer chez quelqu'un état émotif soudain », et ce sens est encore figuré — la même construction est aussi utilisée avec le sens littéral de « donner un coup à qqn » ; cependant il n'est pas question de choisir l'article selon que le terme est abstrait ou non. Il est surtout question de savoir si le nom doit être considéré comme *comptable* ou comme *massique*.

- Il était frappé de stupeur. (*non comptable*)
- Il était frappé d'une stupeur tellement paralysante qu'il ne pouvait plus parler. (*recatégorisation comptable*)
- J'étais frappé d'une stupeur profonde. ([réf.](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/La_confession_d_un_enfant_du_si%C3%A8cle_Oeu/wPlDAQAAMAAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&bsq=%22frapp%C3%A9+d%27+une+stupeur%22&dq=%22frapp%C3%A9+d%27+une+stupeur%22&printsec=frontcover))

Autrement, lorsque l'on utilise la préposition « de » avec le verbe « frapper » au sens *littéral*  de « **donner un coup** » ou au sens *figuré* de « **faire subir une peine ou affliger d'un mal** », « de » signifie « par », « avec ».

- frappé d'un éclat d'obus (*littéral*), il le frappe de la main (*littéral*), il le frappe d'un couteau (*littéral*), frappé d'un mal cruel, mystérieux, inconnu, etc. (*figuré*), …

Le dernier des quatre usages cités (sens littéral) montre que la phrase « 2 » est correcte et c'est aussi cet usage qui montre la phrase « 3 » correcte. La différence se trouve seulement dans la détermination du nom « martelet » ; dans la phrase « 2 » il s'agit d'un martelet quelconque (**un**) alors que dans la phrase « 3 » on fait référence à un martelet connu, le martelet qui est utilisé habituellement dans ce genre de procédure (**de le**).

« Frapper au gong » ne se trouve pas ([frapper au gong](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=frappe+au+gong%2Cfrapper+au+gong&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=30&smoothing=3&direct_url=)). Par contre on dit couramment « frapper *sur* le gong » et « frapper le gong » ([frapper (sur) le gong](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=frapper+sur+le+gong%2Cfrapper+le+gong&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=30&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cfrapper%20sur%20le%20gong%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfrapper%20le%20gong%3B%2Cc0)). Il ne faut pas confondre avec « frapper à la porte », qui ne signifie pas « frapper sur la porte ».

Comment: Merci beaucoup. _il le frappe d'un couteau_ Je l'impression que _il le frappe **avec** un couteau_ sonne mieux. Qu'en pensez-vous ? Par contre, _frappé d'un éclat d'obus_ et _frappé d'un mal cruel_ sont corrects. Je ne dis pas que _il le frappe d'un couteau_  soit incorrect, mais que la même expression avec "avec" serait meilleure.

Comment: _dans la phrase « 2 » il s'agit d'un martelet quelconque (un) alors que dans la phrase « 3 » on fait référence à un martelet connu, le martelet qui est utilisé habituellement dans ce genre de procédure (de le)._ Merci, c'est ce que je pensais mais je n'étais pas sûre.

Comment: _ Il ne faut pas confondre avec « frapper à la porte », qui ne signifie pas « frapper sur la porte »._ Je l'ai trouvé ! [usito](https://usito.usherbrooke.ca/d%C3%A9finitions/frapper)  **frapper à la porte**. Cogner à une porte pour se faire ouvrir. **frapper contre, dans, sur**, etc. Donner un ou plusieurs coups sur (une surface).

Comment: @Oreste « Avec » me semble, à moi aussi, plus parlant dans le cas où  pour frapper on utilise un instrument. // On a tendance à se rabattre sur « l'action de base » mais selon le TLFi la définition de «  Frapper à la porte (ou absol. frapper) » est « demander à entrer » ; on peut être plus spécifique et dire que cela signifie « frapper sur une porte ou se servir du marteau pour demander à entrer » ; de toute façon c'est une expression d'un autre âge, et depuis longtemps déjà elle est concurrencée par « sonner à la porte », laquelle est plus factuelle, mais en ce  nouvel âge (1/2)

Comment: @Oreste du téléphone portable elle ne semble plus tout à fait exacte. (2/2)

Answer (score 1):

*[Martelet](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/martelet)* est un mot très rare et spécialisé. Il est souvent inconnu bien que l'on comprenne facilement de quoi il s'agit dans ce contexte.

Ce n'est cependant pas un objet métallique (marteau ou martelet) qui est utilisé pour frapper sur un gong, au risque de le cabosser rapidement, mais plutôt un [maillet](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maillet) (marteau en bois), le terme spécialisé étant une [mailloche](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mailloche) (maillet enveloppé d'une protection, mot aussi peu courant que martelet).

Je proposerais donc cette phrase :

> **Pour réclamer le silence, A frappe le gong avec un maillet.**

> **Pour réclamer le silence, A frappe le gong d'un coup de maillet.**

Comment: jlliagre, merci ! J'ai regardé des images de martelets et de maillets sur Google Images. :) Parfois, c'est lassant, j'essaie d'écrire sans fautes, mais il y en a de toute façon...

Comment: Il ne faut pas se décourager, c'est en forgeant qu'on devient forgeron ! :-)

Answer (score 1):

On dirait tout simplement « A. donne un/des coup/s de martelet sur le gong pour réclamer le silence. »

(1) et (2) sont incorrects, (3) serait correct si l'on remplaçait le martelet par une partie du corps (A. frappe le gong du pied, du coude, de la tête !).

PS. Avec un martelet il a de bonnes chances de trouer le gong...